# Why doesn't $\sum \frac{sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt(n)}$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Why doesn't $\sum \frac{sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt(n)}$ diverge?

I know that it converges, I just want to know what i'm doing wrong here. Here's what I did.

$\sum\frac{-1}{\sqrt n}  < $  $\sum \frac{sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt n}$ $\sum<\frac{-1}{\sqrt n }$.

Both $\sum\frac{-1}{\sqrt n}$ and $\sum \frac{-1}{\sqrt n} $ diverge by the p series test since p=0.5<1. 
Therefore $\sum \frac{sin(\frac{1}{n})}{\sqrt n}$ also diverges. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: comparison-test is valid for positive series

Comment: $\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac1n\right)}{\sqrt{n}}\sim\dfrac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}$ (asymptotic) which  converges by p series test.

Answer (score 4):

Your implication is wrong. For example, we know that,$$n^2>\sqrt n\  \forall n\in\mathbb N$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\  \forall n\in\mathbb N$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{-1}{\sqrt n}<\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\  \forall n\in\mathbb N$$
$$\Longrightarrow\sum\frac{-1}{\sqrt n}<\sum\frac{1}{n^2}<\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\  \forall n\in\mathbb N$$
But we know that $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, whereas others diverge.

Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

For  $n$ large,  $\sin (1/n) > 0$ and the terms are positive  ,and  using $\sin (1/n)  <  1/n $ we have the given series converges by comparing it with  a $p =:3/2$  series.